# Does eToro's Dividend Growth smart portfolio really pay dividends?

Tags: investing, dividends, broker, dividend-reinvestment

Four months ago I started an investment in Dividend Growth on eToro.
I once read that dividends are not automatically reinvested but actually go straight into one's balance. However, I haven't seen any dividends flowing in.
Is it because it's too early?
Is it because they're actually being reinvested automatically? Perhaps that's why I've noticed a discrepancy between the amount I invested and the sum "current value of the investment + loss" (the latter sum is slightly above the initial investment - however, I read this might be due to spread, is that right?)

In short, does Dividend Growth actually pay dividends, and if it does, do they get reinvested or flow into one's balance?

Comment: Look at a statement, and see what’s happening.  (If you don’t see them in one month, look ar up to three, since dividends might be issued quarterly.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does eToro's Dividend Growth smart portfolio really pay dividends?

Yes. https://www.etoro.com/customer-service/help/75781345/does-etoro-pay-dividends/:

> Does eToro pay dividends? Yes, we do. Your account may be either credited or debited if you are trading a stock, ETF or index that pays a dividend, whether it is a manually opened position or a position within a copy or Smart Portfolio.
>
> See also: [Where can I see my dividend payments?](https://eu1-1.nanorep.com/widget/widget.html?account=etoro&kb=156763#onloadquestionid=1782769502)